# How to get this type of pattern from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the account data from Firebase, note that account can be multiple for example user can store more than 1 account details so i need to get all the account details from this pattern

The code written so far

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot valueRes : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = valueRes.getValue(User.class);
                    mUserList.add(user);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**and below is the error i'm getting from the above code
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap**

The User class consist of an arraylist of accounts!

[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I don't immediately see what the problem is with the code you shared. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll update the question for now yes I'm getting this error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a `List<UserAccount> accounts` field in your `User` class. While the data under `accounts` may look like a list to you at first glance, it **is** actually a `Map` in the database: a set of key/value pairs (the -Md7...` being the key).

So you'll want to change the type to:

```
Map<String, UserAccount> accounts
```